# picture catching focus in recycleview click listener

Tags: android

I'm trying to a clicklistener to catch clicks to my items 
in my Recycleview, 
but most of my view is made of an image, and when i press on the image it doesn't register, 
only when i press outside the image
how can i fix it so that all the card view would catch the click ? 
or set focus to the card everytime you press on the picture ?

this is my adapter:

```
public class cardsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<cardsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<CardModel> albumList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("myTag", "onClick " + getPosition());
        }
    }


    public cardsAdapter(Context mContext, List<CardModel> albumList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.albumList = albumList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CardModel album = albumList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getCountry());
        holder.count.setText(album.getSong());

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("myTag", "onClick ");

            }
        });

//        holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
//            }
//        });
    }



//    /**
//     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
//     */
//    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
//        // inflate menu
//        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
//        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
//        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
//        popup.show();
//    }

//    /**
//     * Click listener for popup menu items
//     */
//    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
//
//        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
//        }
//
//        @Override
//        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
//            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
//                case R.id.action_add_favourite:
//                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    return true;
//                case R.id.action_play_next:
//                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Play next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    return true;
//                default:
//            }
//            return false;
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return albumList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the `Adapter` you provided to create a `RecyclerView` where the items were clickable on both the thumbnail and the parent item view.

Have a look at your XML `card_layout`, ensure that your ImageView hasn't had its `android:clickable` to `false`. Post your `card_layout` XML.

This was the `card_layout` that I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Album"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/thumbnail"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Count"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So foolish of me to not see that, your correct, i just got example of internet and use it, how did i not see that... thank you !